# how to make output text inside nested div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have div inside `div` (nested div) and one `button` click and one `textarea`, when i click this button i want output that `div` in text,and add the text to `Textarea`

example

```
<div id="container">
<div class="nested"> 
 <div id="1">
   <div class="nested">
     <div id="3">helpX</div>
     <div id="4">helpY</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="2">helpZ</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

when i click my button i need the output like this =nested(=nested(helpX)(helpY))(helpZ)

my code is :

```
     $('#BUTTONCLICK').click(function(){
       $('#container').find("div").each( function(index) {
       ....
       }); 
     });
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up some condition to check whether the child is a `nested` or child has `nested` children, or a simple `div`. So I use a recursive function to handle it:

```js
$('#BUTTONCLICK').click(function(){
  var findNest = function(ele) {
    
    // To see if current item needs a nested prefix
    var result = $(ele).hasClass("nested") ? '=nested(' : '';
    
    $(ele).find(' > div').each(function(idx, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        if ($item.hasClass("nested")) {
             // If current cheked item is a nested item, nested it.
            result += findNest($item);
        } else if ($(item).find(".nested").length > 0) {
            result += findNest(item);
        }  else {
            // Current check item is a simple div, add it
            result += '(' + $(item).text() + ')';
        }
    });
    
    // Decide tail
    var tail = $(ele).hasClass("nested") ? ')' : '';
    return result + tail;
  };
     var $container = $('#container');
     var result = findNest($container);

   console.log(result);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <div class="nested"> 
             <div id="1">
                   <div class="nested">
                     <div id="3">helpX</div>
                     <div id="4">helpY</div>
                   </div>
             </div>
             <div id="2">helpZ</div>
        </div> 
</div>
<div id="BUTTONCLICK">click</div>
```

If you want to give a level limit, the code can be changed to:

```
$('#BUTTONCLICK').click(function(){
  // Inits
  var LEVEL_LIMIT = 2;
  var currentLevel = 0;
  var findNest = function(ele) {
    // Add one level at start.
    ++currentLevel;
    // To see if current item needs a nested prefix
    var result = $(ele).hasClass("nested") ? '=nested(' : '';

    $(ele).find(' > div').each(function(idx, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        var $nestChilds = $(item).find(".nested");
        if (currentLevel <= LEVEL_LIMIT &&
            ($item.hasClass("nested") || $nestChilds.length > 0)) {
            // If current cheked item is a nested item, or it has child that is nest, go into it.
            result += findNest($item);
        }  else {
            // Current check item is a simple div or level limit reached, 
            // simply add div texts...(May need other process of text now.)
            result += '(' + $(item).text() + ')';
        }
    });

    // Decrease Level by one before return.
    --currentLevel;

    // Decide tail
    var tail = $(ele).hasClass("nested") ? ')' : '';
    return result + tail;
  };
     var $container = $('#container');
     var result = findNest($container);

   console.log(result);
 });
```

Comment: no words except wow and thanks :)
if I may know where I can add to check if nested length > 1

i mean 
=nested(=nested(=nested((A)(B))(helpY))(helpZ))

Comment: Whats the div structure?

Comment: it must be like this

    `code`
    <div id="container">
                 <div class="nested"> 
                      <div id="1">
                            <div class="nested">
                              <div id="3">
                <div class="nested">
                <div id="5">A</div>
                <div id="6">B</div>
                </div>
                              <div id="4">helpY</div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="2">helpZ</div>
                 </div> 
         </div>

Comment: I've updated my answer, as I find out that when if one `ele`'s child has multilevel nest, the ealier version would iterate though them at the outer loop, and may get unexpected result, the new one just check if it needs to be go down and simply deep down to another level.

Comment: And would you explain 'check if nested length > 1' further? I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Is `<nest><div><nest></nest></div></nest>`  2 level or 3 level?

Comment: Updated my answer, limit level ver at bottom, you may have to handle the situation when max limit is reached, as I only treat them as normal `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#BUTTONCLICK').click(function(){
 var text = '';
 $('#container').find("div").each( function(index) {
     text += $(this).text();
 }); 
 $("textarea").val(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#BUTTONCLICK').click(function(){
  var findNest = function(ele) {
    
    // To see if current item needs a nested prefix
    var result = $(ele).hasClass("nested") ? '=nested(' : '';
    
    $(ele).find(' > div').each(function(idx, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        if ($item.hasClass("nested")) {
             // If current cheked item is a nested item, nested it.
            result += findNest($item);
        } else if ($(item).find(".nested").length > 0) {
            // For all .nested child from the item, do the findNest action
            $(item).find(".nested").each(function(idx, item) {
              result += findNest(item);
          });
        }  else {
            // Current check item is a simple div, add it
            result += '(' + $(item).text() + ')';
        }
    });
    
    // Decide tail
    var tail = $(ele).hasClass("nested") ? ')' : '';
    return result + tail;
  };
     var $container = $('#container');
     var result = findNest($container);

   console.log(result);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <div class="nested"> 
             <div id="1">
                   <div class="nested">
                     <div id="3">helpX</div>
                     <div id="4">helpY</div>
                   </div>
             </div>
             <div id="2">helpZ</div>
        </div> 
</div>
<div id="BUTTONCLICK">click</div>
```